# 'Undefined index notice'

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I just trying to get a value from the row, but it's not happening and I only get a notice which says:

> Notice: Undefined index: sm_value in D:\xampp\htdocs_header.php on line 16

```
<?php
    require "./conf/db.php"; // Additional data

    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION["UserID"])) {
    }
    else {
        header('Location: login.php?=redirect');
    }

    // If user click to logout
    if (isset($_GET["account"]) && $_GET['account'] == "logout") {
        unset($_SESSION["UserID"]);
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: index.php"); // Redirect him/her to index.php
        exit();
    }

    $name = mysqli_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['sm_value']);
    $GetTitle = $mysqli->query("select * from sm_options where sm_value='$name'");
    $row = $GetTitle->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title><?php echo $row['sm_name'];?></title>
        ....
```

Maybe something is wrong with the syntax? Or the method? How do I get the value?

The database looks like this:

[image]

I appreciate any kind of help :)

Comment: Is `$_POST['sm_value']` being sent in the request?

Comment: Hm, not really sure, where should i check that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when your form is not submitted yet.

So you need to add a condition before your statement, something like this:

```
if(!empty($_POST) and array_key_exists("sm_value", $_POST)) {
    $name = mysqli_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['sm_value']);
    $GetTitle = $mysqli->query("select * from sm_options where sm_value='$name'");
    $row = $GetTitle->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    // Every statement and HTML which is required under it when the value is not empty
}
else {
    // An error message, when you say the details are not available.
}
```

Comment: Tried your solution, but still getting notice in the title :(

Comment: okay, not to worry, in programming you have many ways to get a single kind of result. that was one among those, check out the other one now. check my edit. :)

Comment: Hm, seems better, i guess script just doesn't know which value should he get:

<br /> <b>Notice</b>: Undefined variable: row in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\_header.php</b> on line <b>31</b><br />

31 line is the html (where i query the name)

Comment: yes, now enclose all the valid things within the condition, means the query and query related retrievals and displays.

Comment: Sorry, i don't get what you saying :(

Comment: i mean, the complete page should be within the condition.

Comment: thats all?:( i mean understand what you saying, but there is no other way to do it?

Comment: Better add up another condition after the `$row` var declaration, the condition would be something like this, `if(!array_key_exists('sm_name', $row)) { die("value doesn't exist"); }`

Comment: In place of die statement, you can even mention, header redirection to redirect to some place.

Comment: Or another, ideal method is to add default values if not exists. Something like this, `$getTitle= array_key_exists('sm_name', $row) ? $row['sm_name'] : "custom title";` and call the variable `$getTitle` under title tag.